# How can I set the amount by which the sound keys increase/decrease volume?

Tags: audio, keyboard, audio-volume

On my laptop, when I press the volumeup/volumedown key, the sound lever go up/down by 10 units.

I can check that with `alsamixer`: when I press volume up, the sound level indeed go up by 10 points.

But I would like these keys to be less sensible: it would be nice if the level could go up/down by 5 points when I press a key (volume up/volume down).

I know that these rules are configured in `/lib/udev/hwdb.d`, but the only thing I found in these files is the use of the "volumeup" and "volumedown" keywords, but not the amount the button increase/decrease.

How could I do that ?

Is there a config file somewhere ?

### Edit

I'm on arch, and I would like to know where the config is stored (if there is one)

I'm using pulseaudio, I don't know if this can help

Comment: You may be able to do it with a GUI, depending on your DE. In LXQt you just right click on the volume icon in the tray and "Configure Volume Controls".

Comment: It entirely depends on what your system uses to process the volume up/down keys. On my laptop, this doesn't work out of the box, and I've done this within fvwm, and I can control the percentage by changing the configuration. Very likely your Desktop does the same out of the box for you, so that's where you need to start looking: the configuration of your Desktop/Window Manager.

Comment: I found it !
The line was here frome the begining, I feel a bit dumb right now... Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i am concerned this is not a pulseaudio thing and depends on which DE or WM you are using
I have never used a DE with arch but for WM's this is configured in their configuration files like for

- i3 (~/.config/i3/config)

```
#change volume
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%+
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec amixer -q set Master 5%-
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec amixer -q -D pulse set Master toggle
```

- for configuration in dwm (go to dwm dir and configure config.h)

```
#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>
{ 0,  XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume,  spawn,  SHCMD("amixer -q set Master 5%- ") },
{ 0,  XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume,  spawn,  SHCMD("amixer -q set Master 5%+ ") },
```

- for qtiles (.config/qtile/config.py)

```
([], "XF86AudioLowerVolume",  lazy.spawn('amixer -q set Master 3%-')),
([], "XF86AudioRaiseVolume",  lazy.spawn('amixer -q set Master 3%+')),
```